# extract text between two strings in Spotfire

Tags: multiple-columns, spotfire

I want to calculate a new column on Spotfire from data below:

Comment: I downvoted your question because you haven't included any information about what you *have* tried nor really sufficient information to give a constructive answer to your question. do you only need it to work on this exact string? will other strings in other formats in your dataset need numbers pulled from them as well? I have to scold you a little bit because you have been asking questions on this tag long enough to have heard "please include sample data" to know better than to be so vague... also please actually *accept* an answer once in a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want, you just have to replace "Column" by the name of your column.

```
Mid([Column],
    Find("out of ",[Column])+Len("out of "),
    Find(" exposures",[Column])-Find("out of ",[Column])-Len("out of ")
)
```

---

Little explanation:

Mid allows you to extract a substring from a string and two positions/indexes.

Find allows you to get the index of the first match of the first argument into the second.

---

You can find more details about text functions of Spotfire here:
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.2/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_text_functions.htm

Comment: this is probably the best possible answer given the available information. I would have suggested to use `RXReplace()` but @Raj doesn't tell us if the number he needs to extract is always bordered by "out of" and "exposures" or really anything at all, so this is the best possible answer.